# Using Chart.js in functional React component, not allowing me to toggle data: "properties undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to make dynamic data in a Chart.js chart, but how do I make the chart const available to a toggle function?

The chart displays fine, but then I can't update it at all. I believe this is due to scoping. How do I return the Chart.js objects to the main function?

The code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./questions_trends.css";
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';

import { Chart } from "chart.js";

function Trends(){

    const user_context = useContext(UserContext)
    const [positiveChart, setPositiveChart] = React.useState(undefined);

    function makeChart(data){

        // Create the trends chart
        // positive_trend = 
        setPositiveChart = new Chart('positiveChart', {
            type: 'bar',
            data: { 
                labels: data.positive,
                datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Team Positive',
                    data: data.team_positive,
                    backgroundColor: data.color
                },
                {
                    label: 'You Positive',
                    data: data.positive,
                    backgroundColor: data.color
                }]
            },
            options: {
            }
        }); 
    }

    function toggle(value) {
        if(positiveChart.isDatasetVisible(value)){
            positiveChart.hide(value)
        }

        if(!positiveChart.isDatasetVisible(value)){
            positiveChart.show(value)
        }
    }

    useEffect( async () => {
        let result = await axios.get("/api/monthly_tones")
            makeChart(result.data)
    }, []);


    useEffect( async () => {
        return positiveChart.destroy()
    }, []);

    //Render to Dom
    
    return (                    
        <div className="question_positivity_container">
            <canvas id="positiveChart" width="auto" height="70vh"></canvas>

            <button onClick={() => toggle(0)}>See All Cratic</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Trends;
```

The toggle and the useEffect functions don't work: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isDatasetVisible')`

I think this is because the `positiveChart` and `engagedChart` are not in their scope. How do I solve this??

Any help appreciated.

--- **Update**

The solution required using a `const chart = new Chart({})` inside the `makeChart()` function, and then pushing `chart` into state like this: `setPositiveChart(chart)`.

That updated the function state and made the variable available everywhere.

I accepted the answer below because it was the right approach and got me to the answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try using state variables instead of local variables.

Comment: You need to use `useState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `positiveChart` is not in the scope of your other functions because you declare it inside `makeChart`. In order to fix that you must have it in the react useState like this:

```
const [positiveChart, setPositiveChart] = React.useState(undefined);
```

and then inside `makeChart` you can use `setPositiveChart` in order to create it. Afterwards you will be able to access it correctly in your `useEffect` functions.

You can read more about it in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) about state hooks.